# Querying the Cosmos DB Change Feed using SQL queries

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to access Cosmos DB data through a middleware API that gives access to SQL queries but not the change feed (i.e. `DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery()` but not `DocumentClient.CreateDocumentChangeFeedQuery()`). Is it possible to query the change feed using regular SQL queries?

I was thinking about filtering documents on recent `_ts` but I am not sure timestamps are guaranteed to be monotonically increasing across entire collections due to potential clock drift across the VMs Cosmos DB runs on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot query the Change Feed using a SQL query. The Change Feed contains documents that have been inserted / updated, and any filtering needs to be done client-side after receiving such changes.